# Regex - Get text between html tags in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the text between 2 html tags in C#. The providerKey value will change often and there can be multiple tags like this. I am trying to get this value - Barry Todd Smith, MD (129461)

```
<div class="headerLink">

<a href="/AffiliationLetters/VerificationLetter/Report?providerKey=_OG4no3ZLu0SfzRBHPwVs95CgOPx7T9VDVn8RVKS4_9JprRJP-OAjHe20&amp;reportKey=7ILaIBnEn9QuHG42XVvQmn_48-fachhNjhjPccErrPn5oEhDIgWjtHRy0&amp;filtered=True" target="blank">Barry Todd Smith, MD                                                       (129461)</a>

</div>
```

Here is what I have for the regexes. The first one is till - `target="blank">` and the second one is till `- </a>`.

```
<a href="\/AffiliationLetters\/VerificationLetter\/Report[\\?]providerKey[=](.*?)>

<a href="\/AffiliationLetters\/VerificationLetter\/Report[\?]providerKey[=](.*?)<\/a>
```

Comment: Please don't use regex to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Don't use a regex, use something like [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Using a HTML parser or HTMLDom-library is surely more convenient, and also very reliable, but if for some reason using one isn't an option, you can do it with regex without too much headaches by just skipping everything not between the first closing angle bracket and the next opening one - without paying too much attention to the attributes in between.

```
string html = @"<div class=""headerLink"">    
<a href=""/AffiliationLetters/VerificationLetter/Report?providerKey=_OG4no3ZLu0SfzRBHPwVs95CgOPx7T9VDVn8RVKS4_9JprRJP-OAjHe20&amp;reportKey=7ILaIBnEn9QuHG42XVvQmn_48-fachhNjhjPccErrPn5oEhDIgWjtHRy0&amp;filtered=True"" target=""blank"">Barry Todd Smith, MD                                                       (129461)</a>
</div>";    
    
var match = Regex.Match(html, "<a [^<>]+>([^<>]*)");
var anchorValue = match.Result("$1"); // contains 'Barry Todd Smith ...'
```

It would fail if there were unescaped < or > characters in the href-value.

Comment: In my experience, the reason people use regexes to parse HTML is they think a regex is the only way to parse anything and they don't know there are other options.

Comment: I have a string. But when I try to convert it to HTML doc it errors out. That's why I am using regex.          HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); doc.Load(results);                 doc..Load(results) gives me an error for illegal char.